# "Wrong" numbers while referencing lstlistings in text

Tags: cross-referencing, listings

I'm using the lstlisting package to put sourcecode in my pdf file:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ %
language=xml,
basicstyle=\footnotesize,       % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
numbers=none,                   % where to put the line-numbers
xleftmargin=2em,
numberstyle=\footnotesize,      % the size of the fonts that are used for the line-numbers
stepnumber=2,                   % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
frame=yes,                   % adds a frame around the code
tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
captionpos=b,                   % sets the caption-position to bottom
breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
breakatwhitespace=false,        % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
title=\lstname,                 % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting;
                                % also try caption instead of title
escapeinside={(*}{*)},         % if you want to add a comment within your code
morekeywords={*,...},            % if you want to add more keywords to the set
keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
        commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133},
        stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.627,0.126,0.941}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=java,caption={MyCaption}
\label{lst:myLabel}]
See Code-Listing \ref{lst:myLabel}.
\end{document}
```

The problem is that in the caption I see the (correct) "Listing 7.2", in my text I see "5" but I want the "7.2" there too :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to supply the label among the keys:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=java,caption={MyCaption},label=lst:myLabel]
```

Page 16 of the manual (not very easy to find, though).